# Umlaut trouble, deleting inputenc results in Unicode trouble

Tags: errors

I am having trouble modifying files from my German colleague.

Previously, I removed the line:

```
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
```

this was as I saw umlauts being changed to percent signs whenever I modified anything.

Now I have the problem that when I remove:

```
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
```

I receive the message:
"This file was opened with IsoLatin9 encoding. This file could not be opened with Unicode (UTF-8) encoding because it was not saved with that encoding. If you wish to open in another encoding, close the window and open again."

I'm sorry to write I'm quite new with TeX, if anyone has a suggestion, I'd be VERY grateful.

thanks and with kind regards,
Brian

Comment: Welcome. // Please Edit your question to provide relevant code: 1) We can copy and compile it. 2) It shows all code relevant to demonstrate your problem. 3) Everything else is removed.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? It depends on your IDE, but normally just click "save as", then choose "UTF8" as the resulting encoding.

Comment: well try to do what the dialog suggests: close your editor and reopen everything. Perhaps your editor than uses the correct file encoding. If it is still wrong make a backup of the files before you try to change something.